# AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor throws error on appendChild()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I don't really expect an answer for this question as the error occurs in a .net generated script resource file.

The error is IE only.
It happens on Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v.
Error is "HierarchyRequestError" in line `this._doc.appendChild(iframe);`

Complete code (ctrl+c):

```
_contentCopy: function(text, prize, word) {
    if (text != "") {
        text = text.replace(/(<td[^>]*?>)([\s ]*?)(<\/td[^>]*?>)/ig, "$1&nbsp;$3")
            .replace(/(<td[^>]*?>)\s*(&nbsp;)\s*(<\/td[^>]*?>)/ig, "$1<br/>$3")
            .replace(/(<p[^>]*?>)\s*(&nbsp;)\s*(<\/p[^>]*?>)/ig, "$1<br/>$3");
    }

    var iframe = this._doc.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.width = "0";
    iframe.height = "0";
    if (Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.isIE) {
        iframe.src = "javascript:false;";
    }
    this._doc.appendChild(iframe);
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    doc.write("<html><head></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>");
    doc.close();
    doc.body.contentEditable = true;
    var r = doc.body.createTextRange();
    var wasNbsp = false;
    //More code
```

Is there a way to fix this even though its a an auto generated script file, or is there maybe something on my page that could interfere and cause this?